# Converting R if (seed) statement into Python

Tags: python, r, if-statement, random-seed

Working on a project for my Stats class and I've hit a roadblock...

I need to convert this code, given by the professor...

```
# Set seed if required and determine if seed is not an integer  
#   
       if(!is.null(seed)) {   
              if(is.integer(seed)) set.seed(seed)   
              else stop("Non NULL or Integer Seed") 
       }
```

...into Python.  I thought i got it right, but I'm coming up short with this expression.

```
 if seed != None :   
              if is_integer(seed) :
              rd.seed(seed)  
                  return
              else :
                  sys.exit("Non NULL or Integer Seed")
```

It gives me a "IndentationError: expected an indented block".  Can you seed in Python without immediately following it with random.randint()?

Comment: Wow, that was super easy.  You people are great, thank you!!!

Comment: Wait, now it's giving me a "'TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable"

Answer (score 1):

The indentation problem is at `rd.seed(seed)` line:

```py
if seed != None:   
    if is_integer(seed):
      rd.seed(seed)  
      return
else:
  sys.exit("Non NULL or Integer Seed")
```

Comment: Wait, now it's giving me a "'TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable"

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with the identations!
Your code should be look like this:

```
if seed != None:   
    if is_integer(seed):
        rd.seed(seed)  
        return
else:
    sys.exit("Non NULL or Integer Seed")
```

Comment: No need to add an answer if there is already one. Especially if they are the same.